# Dockerized Spring boot app connect to mongoDB docker image not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I try to figure out why the communication between dockerized Spring boot app and mongoDB is not working. First things first:
The whole microservice is running localy perfectly.
I create an application.properties with the profile name docker:
application-docker.properties

```
server.port=8091
spring.application.name=customer
# ============================================================================================================
# EUREKA
# It's not possible to use localhost in the docker container. Instate use the container name.
# In this case "eureka-server". See the file docker-compose.yml to check the container name.
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
# ============================================================================================================
# ZIPKIN
# It's not possible to use localhost in the docker container. Instate use the container name.
# In this case "zipkin". See the file docker-compose.yml to check the container name.
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://zipkin:9411
# ============================================================================================================
# RABBIT_MQ
# It's not possible to use localhost in the docker container. Instate use the container name.
# In this case "rabbitmq". See the file docker-compose.yml to check the container name.
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=rabbitmq:5672
rabbitmq.exchanges.internal=internal.exchange
rabbitmq.queue.notification=notification.queue
rabbitmq.routing-keys.internal-notification=internal.notification.routing-key
# ============================================================================================================
# MONGO-DB
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
#spring.data.mongodb.database=data
#spring.data.mongodb.host=spring
#spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/data
```

and then the docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
    networks:
      - spring

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8095:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    networks:
      - spring
    
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    networks:
      - spring

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - spring

  eureka-server:
    image: koulombus/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin

  api-gateway:
    image: koulombus/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server

  customer:
    image: koulombus/customer:latest
    container_name: customer
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb

  fraud:
    image: koulombus/fraud:latest
    container_name: fraud
    ports:
      - 8092:8092
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq

  notification:
    image: koulombus/notification:latest
    container_name: notification
    ports:
      - 8093:8093
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
  data: {}

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge
```

after starting docker...

```
mvn clean package -P "build-docker-image"
docker compose up -d
```

> Facts

**Eureka-Server:**
[image]

**Ziplin:**
[image]

**RabbitMQ:**
[image]

**Mongo-express:**
[image]

> Problem
> When I check now the customer log in docker i facet following:

```
 ,-----. ,--. ,--.  ,---.   ,--------.  ,-----.  ,--.   ,--. ,------. ,------.

'  .--./ |  | |  | '   .-'  '--.  .--' '  .-.  ' |   `.'   | |  .---' |  .--. '

|  |     |  | |  | `.  `-.     |  |    |  | |  | |  |'.'|  | |  `--,  |  '--'.'

'  '--'\ '  '-'  ' .-'    |    |  |    '  '-'  ' |  |   |  | |  `---. |  |\  \

 `-----'  `-----'  `-----'     `--'     `-----'  `--'   `--' `------' `--' '--'


Application Name: 

Application Version: 

:: Spring Boot ::                 (v2.6.3)



2022-03-03 08:58:55.187  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] c.k.customer.CustomerApplication         : Starting CustomerApplication using Java 17.0.1 on cf6b5b41507d with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)

2022-03-03 08:58:55.241  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] c.k.customer.CustomerApplication         : The following profiles are active: docker

2022-03-03 08:59:01.557  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2022-03-03 08:59:02.239  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 667 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.

2022-03-03 08:59:04.589  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=9e7fc4f4-3641-3895-b9a0-4754b711f194

2022-03-03 08:59:08.906  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8091 (http)

2022-03-03 08:59:08.952  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2022-03-03 08:59:08.953  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]

2022-03-03 08:59:09.454  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2022-03-03 08:59:09.454  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 13490 ms

2022-03-03 08:59:12.729  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongodb:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}

2022-03-03 08:59:13.071  INFO [customer,,] 1 --- [}-mongodb:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27017


com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb

at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb

at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:887) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[na:na]

at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]

... 6 common frames omitted
```

Somewhere I make a mistake. I would be very grateful for a hint.

Comment: Change this "spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/data" to  
"spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017" and "spring.data.mongodb.database=data"

Comment: > Thx for your response. 
I think I have to specify like that:
uri:mongodb://rootuser:rootpass@localhost:27017/data
... but that is the same like..
"spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser", 
"spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass", 
"spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost", 
"spring.data.mongodb.port=27017", 
"spring.data.mongodb.database=data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, working solution for me:

**application-docker.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=data
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
    networks:
      - spring

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8095:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - spring

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    networks:
      - spring

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - spring

  eureka-server:
    image: koulombus/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin

  api-gateway:
    image: koulombus/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server

  customer:
    image: koulombus/customer:latest
    container_name: customer
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb
      - fraud

  fraud:
    image: koulombus/fraud:latest
    container_name: fraud
    ports:
      - 8092:8092
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb

  notification:
    image: koulombus/notification:latest
    container_name: notification
    ports:
      - 8093:8093
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
  data: {}

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an 's' in `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in your config file.

Comment: THX, I fixed that, but this was not solving the problem.